# Sorting elements within a tuple (getting the highest)

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

Let's say I have the following tuple (python):

```
scores = {'player1':200,'player2':300,'player3':150}
```

The reason I have one tuple and not a list of tuples is so that I can update the scores very easily, i.e.

```
scores['player1'] += 50
```

How can I get the player that scored the highest?
Or sort the players by their scores:

```
[player2, player1, player3]
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is a *dictionary*, not a tuple.

Comment: It's not a duplicate if only the `max` is wanted. Sorting's a waste in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the built-in `sorted` function: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

**sorted(iterable[, cmp[, key[, reverse]]])**

You could specify the item of dictionary as key, and set reverse to `True` so that you could get a list of scores in descending order.

```
>>> scores = {'player1':200,'player2':300,'player3':150}
>>> max_score = sorted(scores, key=scores.__getitem__, reverse=True)[0]
>>> max_score
'player2'
```

As a side note, `scores.__getitem__(i)` is roughly the same as `scores[i]`.

```
>>> scores.__getitem__('player1')
200
>>> scores['player1']
200
```